# XMPP error reply received from myroom@conference.****/myroom@conference.****: XMPPError: item-not-found - cancel

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, multiuserchat

I am not able to join the room. I have gone through the documentation [XMPP Instant Room Error](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#createroom-instant)

Here is how i am creating instant room:

```
 try {
        UserSearchManager usm = new UserSearchManager(Utils.connection);

        List<DomainBareJid> services = usm.getSearchServices();

        String roomjid = "myroom@" + services.get(0);

        mucJid = JidCreate.entityBareFrom(roomjid);
        Log.d(TAG, mucJid.toString());

        // Create the nickname.
        nickname = Resourcepart.from(roomjid);

        Log.d(TAG, nickname.toString());
    } catch (XmppStringprepException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Get the MultiUserChatManager
    manager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(Utils.connection);

    // Get a MultiUserChat using MultiUserChatManager
    MultiUserChat muc = manager.getMultiUserChat(mucJid);

    // Create the room and send an empty configuration form to make this an instant room
    try {

        // Prepare a list of owners of the new room
        Set<Jid> owners = JidUtil.jidSetFrom(new String[] { "54321@rahul", "12345@rahul" });

        muc.create(nickname)
                .getConfigFormManager()
                .setRoomOwners(owners)
                .submitConfigurationForm();

        muc.sendConfigurationForm(new Form(DataForm.Type.submit));

        muc.join(nickname);

        EntityBareJid invitemucJid = JidCreate.entityBareFrom("12345@rahul");
        muc.invite(invitemucJid, "testing");
    } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MultiUserChatException.MucAlreadyJoinedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MultiUserChatException.MissingMucCreationAcknowledgeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MultiUserChatException.NotAMucServiceException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmppStringprepException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MultiUserChatException.MucConfigurationNotSupportedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The MUC room is getting created successfully. But when i am checking through Invitation Listener and trying to join the room. It is giving error.

The Invitation listener code is as follow:

```
    try {

        Resourcepart nickname = Resourcepart.from(room.getRoom().toString());

        room.join(nickname);

        Log.d(TAG, "room status---> " + room.isJoined());

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (room.isJoined()) {
                    Toast.makeText(FriendListActivity.this, "Joined", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(FriendListActivity.this, "Not joined", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    } catch (XmppStringprepException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MultiUserChatException.NotAMucServiceException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Below is screen shot of the stack Trace

[image]

As per the documentation it says that the MUC room is locked. But I have created instant room along with default configuration.

Comment: Which software is hosting the MUC component?

Comment: I am currently using OpenFire and my Smack version is 4.2.0

Comment: Any help would be appreciated

Comment: same problem with me now.. any solution. @RahulAgrawal

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a network error, I do somethings wrong if I use Wifi but get corrcet result with cellular network.

Comment: item-not-found is a XMPP error, i.e., o. layer 4. So the lower OSI layers are functional.